# Do Nizari Ismaili Shias believe in the infallibility of all the Imams?

Tags: shiism, shia-imam, imamah, infallability

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nizari):

> The Nizari Ismailis have always maintained that the Imamah (also known as 'Imamat') can only be inherited from the current Imam to a direct descendant in a father-to-son (or grandson) hereditary lineage starting with Imam Ali and then to Imam Hussain and so on until their present and living 49th Imam, Prince Karim al-Husayni Aga Khan IV.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infallibility):

> In Shi'a theology, the belief is that the Ahl al-Bayt, including Muhammad, his daughter Fatima Zahra and **Shi'a Imams** are all infallible and do not make mistakes.

According to Nizaris, they believe the Imamah continues.

**Question:** Do Nizari Ismaili Shias believe in the infallibility of all the Imams?

As stated above, Shias believe that their Imams are infallible. **Do Nizaris believe in infallibility and if they do so they believe in the infallibility of all the Imams, including the present** [**Aga Khan**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aga_Khan)?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, Imam in reality or the Eternal Iman(Nur) is infallible, but the human reflection of Eternal Iman, or what we should call the "historical Iman", they are fallible. We shouldn't mixture the doctrine of "manifestation" in Ismaili theology as the doctrine of incarnation in various type of Orthodox Christianity.
The historical Imams are all human reflection of the Noor, not the Noor in human fresh, they are pure soul and thus can reflects the Noor, we aren't pure thus cannot reflects so.

Comment: The other Muslim brothers who accept the legitimate Imamanmate of the descendant of Imam Ali, they might considers all Imams to be infallible, just as some Sunnis would considers the Prophet himself as such. Ismaili doctrine on Noor as the Eternal Imam, it can explains the matter of infallible without idolizing the Prophets and his descendant.

Comment: If your comment is part of your answer then use the edit link and add it, else  be warned that comments are deleted because they are meant to improve or an answer or to help improving/elaborating answers.